# VBScript permission denied error 800A0046 in CreateTextFile suddenly started occurring

Tags: vbscript

I have been using a particular VBScript for a long time and it suddenly broke today with a permission denied error.  The line number referenced as the error points to a call to CreateTextFile as the problem.  I have simplified the script to 4 lines and still get the error.  Here is the simplified 4 line script:

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutputFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("test.txt", True)
objOutputFile.WriteLine("test")
objOutputFile.Close
```

When I run this script I get:

```
Line:    2 
Char:    1 
Error:   Permission denied 
Code:    800A0046 
Source:  Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

This is on a stand-alone Windows 10 PC, and I have changed nothing to do with user or file system permissions on my computer and have not modified the script prior to its breaking.

Just for grins, I verified that System, Administrators, and my user ID all have Full, Modify, Read & execute, List folder contents, Read, and Write permissions.  That all looks good.  I can copy files, delete files, open notepad and create or edit files, etc., so it doesn't seem to be a permissions problem.

It only seems to affect writing to my user profile.  For example, if I run the following code, it fails in line 5, not line 2:

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutputFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\test.txt", True)
objOutputFile.WriteLine("test")
objOutputFile.Close
Set objOutputFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Username\Documents\Test\test.txt", True)
objOutputFile.WriteLine("test")
objOutputFile.Close
```

I can work around the problem by doing the following, but I should really not have to do this:

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutputFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\test.txt", True)
objOutputFile.WriteLine("test")
objOutputFile.Close
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run "cmd.exe /C copy ""C:\Temp\test.txt"" ""C:\Users\Username\Documents\Test\test.txt"" "
```

What gives?  Has Microsoft changed something that broke writing files with VBScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a fully qualified filename such as `C:\temp\test.txt` that will probably help.

Comment: In the long version of the script that broke I was passing the fully qualified name to CreateTextFile.  For the purposes of a simple example I used "test.txt" as the file name, but in my troubleshooting I also tried fully qualified names.  Same problem.

Comment: Could it be that for some reason the file is in use/blocked? By AV perhaps? I know it may sound silly, but have you tried a reboot, just to be sure?

Comment: I tried a reboot, and I tried shutting down AVG antivirus.  Same problem.  But this is curious, if I run this script
```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutputFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\test.txt", True)
objOutputFile.WriteLine("test")
objOutputFile.Close
Set objOutputFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\UserName\Documents\test.txt", True)
objOutputFile.WriteLine("test")
objOutputFile.Close
```
it fails on line 5, not line 2.  It seems that anything I try within my user profile fails.

Comment: FYI, the file I am creating is a new file, not existing, so it can't be locked or in use by another program.